BadConvexModuleIdentifier: Hit an error while pushing when doing 'npx convex dev'
I am using Convex for the first time and i just added all my files:

However when i hit npx convex dev i get this error,
Error fetching POST  https://enchanted-buffalo-216.convex.cloud/api/push_config 400 Bad Request: BadConvexModuleIdentifier: Hit an error while pushing:
_.._/_.._/_.._/HTML_CSS_JS/resumatch-ai/convex/auth.config.js is not a valid path to a Convex module. Path component _.._ must have at least one alphanumeric character.

I saw that it looked at .js files so i changed the .ts to .js, but it did not help.

Your HTML_CSS_JS file has '/' so you need to replace that with something else. Folder names cannot have '/' in them.
